# Some conflicts were found in the installation area, rt.jar modefied

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-studio-3.3

I'm trying to update android studio to 3.3, my current version is 3.2.1

I downloaded the update several times and every time I had two problems, the first one said that a file wasn't expected so I deleted it, the other one

[image: The error that appears after the update is downloaded]

Now I don't know what to do with this, I've seen a lot of questions which were similar but the answers didn't solve my problem.

I also looked for rt.jar to download it but I didn't find it anywhere.
I tried to delete it and move it but it was useless.

Comment: `rt.jar` is the central library JAR file of your Java Runtime(JRE) installation. Reinstall your used JRE.

Comment: I can see here https://java.com/en/download/help/linux_uninstall.xml  that the directory I delete is not the directory where the problem really occurs, the problem exists in android-studio/jre/jre so can I reinstall this in the android studio ?

Comment: Redownload Android Studio. I should contain a full Java runtime including `rt.jar`.